# How to use safely wordpress $wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress website. I need to display dynamic data from a table of my database and display them in one of my pages. 
I used the following code (in my page) to retrieve my data:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM myTable" );
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
echo '<tr>'; 
echo '<td align="center">' . $print->fieldA. '</td>';
echo '<td align="center">' . $print->fieldB. '</td>';
echo '<td align="center">' . $print->fieldC . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Everything is working properly and I can see the data on my page.
The problem is that if I do a right click on my page and select "View page source" on my brower, then everyone can see my query. 
I think this is not very safe. How can I convert my code so no one can see my table name and fields?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your code there's nothing that would output the raw database query to the page, unless you're talking about something else?

Comment: Although there is another problem with your code - you don't even try to escape html entities (what will happen if there is `</td>` in fieldA? ;))

Comment: This is a part of my code, not the whole code. I want to display my data into a table. That's why I use <td>. 
The code is working properly and I get my data. 

The problem is that If I do a right click on my web page and select "View page source" on my brower, then everyone can see my query, my table name etc.